# What is this seedling I found sprouted in my sink?

Tags: identification, seedlings

I found a seed that had sprouted unnoticed in my sink. I never saw the seed. By the time I saw anything it was a sprout. Curious as to what it is, I planted it. The first two true leaves have now emerged. Any idea what this is?

[image: Seedling]

Comment: Do you recall what the seed looked like?

Comment: I never saw the seed. By the time I saw anything it was a sprout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like maybe a pepper of some sort.

Comment: A pepper! I thought the leaves looked familiar, but couldn't say why. But I'm sure you're right that it is a pepper. I must have cleaned the seeds from one and at least one seed found its way under the rubber mat and sprouted in the wire mesh of the drain.

Comment: Plants are remarkable in their ability to find a place to grow!

Comment: It's amazing that plants can thrive in such harsh conditions, yet some still die when pampered :(

Comment: It is interesting to see how this plant survived. But I suspect the pepper was a hybrid so this seedling will not be true to type. I'm not sure if it is worth growing, but having coming this far, I'll keep it going.